# How can I export data into excel from a grid which contains image?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, export-to-excel

I want to export data in to excel from grid which contains image.

Am using the following code -

```
 private void CreateXL()
 {
    Response.Clear();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=xxxxxxxt.xls");
    Response.Charset = "";

    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
    StringWriter objStringWriter = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter objHtmlTextWriter = new HtmlTextWriter(objStringWriter);

    Gridview.RenderControl(objHtmlTextWriter);
    Response.Write(objStringWriter.ToString());
    Response.End();
 }
```

But in excel am not able to see the images, instead of an image am getting a message that says, 'The linked image cannot be displayed The file may have been moved, renamed or deleted. Verify the links points to the correct file and location.'

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: This URL will definitely helps you a lot.... http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-with-Images-to-Word-Excel-and-PDF-Formats-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Comment: is that work for you????????

Answer (score 0):

Full article : http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Export-GridView-with-Images-to-Word-Excel-and-PDF-Formats-in-ASP.Net.aspx

```
private void Excel_Export()
{
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
GridView1.AllowPaging = false;
GridView1.DataBind();

for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[i];
//Apply text style to each Row
row.Attributes.Add("class", "textmode");
}
GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
//style to format numbers to string
string style = @"<style> .textmode { mso-number-format:\@; } </style>";
Response.Write(style);
Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
}
```